# Questions about nmap

Tags: networking, nmap

I have several questions about `nmap`. First, `nmap` can detect servers via:

- link-layer
- network-layer
- transport-layer

What are the differences (not in the layer, but in the way that `nmap` does it) and how does `nmap` do this?

Second, when I port scan with `nmap`, the UDP scan takes much longer then the TCP scan. Why?

Third: are there any different methods to explore the OS then to use the `-O --osscan-guess` command (I mean totally different, not e.)?

Comment: I strongly suggest asking one question per question. Further, a lot of these are answered in the manpage—have you read it? I believe it answers your first two questions in depth.

Answer (score 1):

I can address your third question.

One totally different way to identify an operating system is using Michal Zalewski's [p0f](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f.shtml). p0f guesses operating systems based on particular flags and other characteristics of TCP packets that pass by. A SYN packet from an incoming connection is enough to make a guess. The "fingerprint" file from Zalewski's site is kind of old.  Newer [fingerprint files](https://tools.netsa.cert.org/confluence/display/tt/p0f+fingerprints) exist.

Comment: Actually, this isn't right. A UDP packet sent to a closed port does send a reply (but those replies are rate limited, which is the major cause of slowness). Packet loss is a pretty minor problem (except on broken networks). If you look under `-sU` in the nmap manpage, there are several paragraphs answering that question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you don't want to look into the source code because of its complexity. A book that describes in a simple way how nmap functions and what are the differences between its scanning techniques is [Secrets of Network Cartography: A Comprehensive Guide to nmap](http://www.networkuptime.com/nmap/index.shtml) (available online for free). For more documentation, check [the docs on nmap.org](http://nmap.org/docs.html)

Answer (score 1):

The short answers to your questions are below. The long answer is, "read the [manpage](http://nmap.org/book/man.html)." The Really Long Answer is, check out the source code.

1. Host discovery ("detect servers")

   For hosts on the same link as the scanner, Nmap uses ARP requests to determine the link-layer address of each IP address being scanned. Any positive reply is taken to mean that the host is up. The `--send-ip` option can be used to override this behavior.

   For all other hosts, Nmap uses a combination of ICMP and TCP packets to attempt to solicit a response. This could be described as "network-layer" or even "transport-layer" discovery. Briefly, an ICMP Echo request should produce a Echo response, a TCP SYN should produce a TCP SYN-ACK or RST, a TCP ACK should produce a TCP RST, and an ICMP timestamp request should produce a timestamp response.
2. UDP takes longer to scan because an open port does not have to return a reply. TCP scans can expect an immediate reply, whether open or closed, for each port that is not firewalled (filtered). UDP scans get the same reply for open and filtered ports (with some exceptions. See the documentation on [UDP payloads](http://nmap.org/book/nmap-payloads.html)). Furthermore, many hosts rate-limit the closed-port response (ICMP port unreachable response), so even closed ports can only be determined slowly.
3. Some services running on a target system can divulge the Operating System, so running a service version scan (`-sV`) could give that information. Also, many of the [NSE scripts](http://nmap.org/nsedoc) that come with Nmap can get similar information. However, these methods are often less reliable than using `-O`, and depend on particular services being available.